# How to get the all mondays in a month?

Tags: mysql

I want to get all the **Mondays** in the month of MAY 2015

(using mysql query)

OUTPUT:

```
MON   
04  
11  
18  
25
```

Comment: As an aside, for a longer term more scalable solution have a look at calendar tables; https://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select row+1  as Mon from   
( SELECT @row := @row + 1 as row FROM
  (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6) t1,
  (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6) t2,
  (SELECT @row:=-1) t3 limit 31 ) b where
         DATE_ADD('2015-05-01', INTERVAL ROW DAY) between '2015-05-01' and '2015-05-31' and DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD('2015-05-01', INTERVAL ROW DAY))=2;
```

Output

```
+------------+
| Mon        |
+------------+
|          4 |
|         11 |
|         18 |
|         25 |
+------------+
```

Tweaking a bit this [query](http://www.htlinux.com/mysql-get-all-sundays-in-a-month/)

Answer (score 1):

For reference, here's another solution - note that the last entry may be null, can be changed to another value if necessary, or wrap in a sub-select and filter on not null.

```
SET @date='2015-05-01';
SET @offset=7 - WeekDay(@date);

SELECT DAY(DATE_ADD(@date,INTERVAL @offset DAY)) AS 'MON'
UNION SELECT DAY(DATE_ADD(@date,INTERVAL @offset+7 DAY))
UNION SELECT DAY(DATE_ADD(@date,INTERVAL @offset+14 DAY))
UNION SELECT DAY(DATE_ADD(@date,INTERVAL @offset+21 DAY))
UNION DISTINCT SELECT IF(DAY(DATE_ADD(@date,INTERVAL @offset+28 DAY))>21,
            DAY(DATE_ADD(@date,INTERVAL @offset+28 DAY)),
            DAY(DATE_ADD(@date,INTERVAL @offset+21 DAY)))
;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa4ce/4

Comment: Nice. `7 - WEEKDAY()` gets the number of days we need to advance to get to the following Monday. The query could be tweaked to avoid returning the extra NULL row for months that don't contain a fifth Monday.

Comment: Since the query is using `UNION`, we could just replace `null` with an expression returned for one of the other rows; and the UNION set operator will remove the duplicate.

Comment: Thats true, I want aware of `UNION DISTINCT` - updated query in response.

Comment: The `DISTINCT` keyword isn't necessary following `UNION`. A `UNION` is implicitly a `UNION DISTINCT`. We only get a different behavior when we specify `UNION ALL`. A `UNION ALL` doesn't perform the operation to remove duplicates, which is why that's generally faster than a `UNION`.

Comment: I don't think this query returns a correct result when `@date` itself is a Monday. It looks like the query skips that, and returns the next Monday.

Answer (score 0):

This query returns the two digit day value of the Mondays in a month.

This requires the "month" as a date of the first day of the month, as a value in the SELECT list of the first inline view (d0).  (This inline view query could be tweaked to handle any date value within a month as the specification for a month.)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(d0.dt + INTERVAL d1.i*6+d2.i DAY,'%d')   AS dd
 --  , d0.dt + INTERVAL d1.i*6+d2.i DAY                     AS dt
  FROM ( SELECT '2015-05-01' + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS dt 
       ) d0
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT 0 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5
       ) d1
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT 0 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5
       ) d2
 WHERE d0.dt + INTERVAL d1.i*6+d2.i DAY < d0.dt + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
   AND NOT WEEKDAY(d0.dt + INTERVAL d1.i*6+d2.i DAY)
 ORDER BY 1
```

NOTE: This requires the month to be specified only *once*, in the first inline view (d0). Everything else is handled in expression that reference this one value.

The `WEEKDAY` function returns 0 for a date value that is a Monday, so a `NOT` on the return from the WEEKDAY function will return `TRUE` for a Monday.

For a supplied date value of '2015-05-01', this returns:

```
dd
--
04
11
18
25
```

Comment: [SQL Fiddle demonstration HERE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b900/4](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b900/4)